# Im trying to access a specific field from our userData to determine what type of user it is. What is the most simple way to do this?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

This is our Firebase Database userData collection:

[image]

[And this is where I attempt to get that "admin" information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHIGf.png)

I am simply trying to access this information from within the widget to determine where I can or cannot send the current user.

Any advice on how I can simplify this? Or if I am doing this the best way?

Comment: This is perfectly fine

Comment: @DJHemath well it doesn’t work….

Comment: What do you mean by "It doesn't work"? Firebase returns something wrong? Or you're not able to redirect the user?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @DJHemath sorry. Should have been more specific. What I’m trying to do later on in the widget is before I navigate away, I try and check whether that field is set to true or false. Basically I cast the variable I created to a String with .toString() and then see if it’s equal to “true”. If it is I navigate to one place, if not I navigate to another. However, it looks like that’s not working because the comparison doesn’t affect the result. It goes into the else statement even if I change the if statement to check for “false.”